# Washing for Bread: Need to Do So Again

Tags: halacha, netilat-yadayim-washing

I heard that one who washed for bread would needs to wash again for if he:
a) touched the hand of one who did not wash,
b) touch a normally covered part of your body, 
c) touched excrement (i.e. changing a baby’s diaper)

Where is the source for this found in *halachah*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could start with the Kitzur Shulchan Aruch in סימן מ - הלכות נטילת ידים לסעודה

> סעיף ו': אִם לְאַחַר שֶׁשָּׁפַךְ הַמַּיִם עַל יָדוֹ אַחַת, נָגַע שָׁם בְּיָדוֹ הַשְּׁנִיָּה, אוֹ אָדָם אַחֵר נָגַע שָׁם, אֲזַי נִטְמְאוּ הַמַּיִם שֶׁעַל יָדוֹ, וְצָרִיךְ לְנַגְּבָן וְלִטּוֹל פַּעַם שֵׁנִית. אַךְ אִם אֵרַע לוֹ כֵּן לְאַחַר שֶׁכְּבָר בֵּרֵךְ לֹא יְבָרֵךְ שֵׁנִית. ‏

If you pour water over one hand and then touch the dry hand or **you then touch somebody else's hand**, you have to dry both hands and start again.

If you did so [touch somebody else's hand - before you dry your hands] after you already made the Bracha - וְצִוָּנוּ עַל נְטִילַת יָדָיִם - [you have to dry & wash again] but you do not repeat the Bracha.

> סעיף טז': מִי שְׁבְּאֶמְצַע סְעוּדָּה נָגַע בְּגוּפוֹ בַּמְּקוֹמוֹת הַמְכֻסִּים, אוֹ שֶׁחִכֵּךְ בְּרֹאשׁוֹ, אוֹ שֶׁהִשְׁתִּין מַיִם, צָרִיךְ לִטּוֹל יָדָיו פַּעַם שֵׁנִית, אֲבָל לֹא יְבָרֵךְ עֲלֵיהֶן. וְכֵן אֲפִלּוּ אִם עָשָׂה צְרָכָיו וְנוֹטֵל יָדָיו בְּאֶמְצַע הַסְּעוּדָּה, אֵינוֹ צָרִיךְ לְבָרֵךְ עַל נְטִילַת יָדָיִם. ‏

In the middle of a meal (IOW: after you have washed your hands) you **touch parts of your body that are normally covered**, or you scratch your head, or you **urinate**, you have to wash again, but you do not make another Bracha.

Even if **you relieved yourself** during the meal and washed again, you do not make another Bracha.

BTW: As the Shulchan Aruch in סימן ד - דיני נטילת ידים and the Kitzur in 2:9 Pasken, your (b) and (c) **always require washing hands.**

> יח אֵלּוּ דְּבָרִים צָרִיךְ נְטִילָה בְּמַיִם. הַקָּם מֵהַמִּטָּה וְהַיּוֹצֵא מִבֵּית הַכִּסֵא. וּמִבֵּית הַמֶּרְחָץ. וְהַנּוֹטֵל צִפָּרְנָיו. וְהַחוֹלֵץ מִנְעָלָיו. וְהַנּוֹגֵעַ בְּרַגְלָיו. וְהַחוֹפֵף רֹאשׁוֹ, וְיֵשׁ אוֹמְרִים אַף הַהוֹלֵךְ בֵּין הַמֵּתִים. וּמִי שֶׁנָּגַע  בְּמֵת. וּמִי  שֶׁמְּפַלֵּא כֵּלָיו. וְהַמְשַׁמֵּשׁ מִטָּתוֹ. וְהַנּוֹגֵעַ בְּכִנָּה. וְהַנּוֹגֵעַ בְּגוּפוֹ בְּיָדוֹ. וּמִי שֶׁעָשָׂה אַחַת מִכָּל אֵלּוּ וְלֹא נָטַל, אִם תַּלְמִיד חָכָם הוּא תַּלְמוּדוֹ מִשְׁתַּכֵּחַ. וְאִם אֵינוֹ תַּלְמִיד חָכָם יוֹצֵא מִדַּעְתּוֹ. ‏